# error inserting parts sqlite

Tags: android, sqlite

I have 2 tables Quotes and Parts.Now for particular quote Id there can be multiple parts but for that quote id no duplicate part can be there.
For eg

```
for quote 1 there can be part A,B,C
and for quote 2 there can be A,B
```

My query is how to restrict same part say A to be inserted into quote 1 if part A is already present but allow part A to be inserted for quote B

Code for inserting data

```
public synchronized boolean add(WO_quotes object) {
        long result = -1;

        if (object == null) {
            return false;
        } else {
            mSQLiteDB = mOpenHelper.getWritableDatabase();
            ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
            int i = 0;
            values.put(param[i++], object.Company_Code);
            values.put(param[i++], object.IWO_No);
            values.put(param[i++], object.wo_no);
            values.put(param[i++], object.wo_description);
            values.put(param[i++], object.IWO_Status_Code);
            values.put(param[i++], object.IWO_Type_Code);
            values.put(param[i++], object.IEQ_Code);
            values.put(param[i++], object.Icustomer_Code);
            values.put(param[i++], object.WO_From_Type);
            values.put(param[i++], object.Sub_Total);
            values.put(param[i++], object.Total_Tax);
            values.put(param[i++], object.Discount);
            values.put(param[i++], object.Shipping_Charges);
            values.put(param[i++], object.Total_cost);
            values.put(param[i++], object.Bench_Fee);
            values.put(param[i++], object.Wo_Service_location_Type);
            values.put(param[i++], object.Misc_Part);
            values.put(param[i++], object.Shop_Supplies);
            values.put(param[i++], object.Iterm_ID);

            try {
                String selctQuery=""
                result = mSQLiteDB
                        .insert(DbTable_WO_quotes.Table, null, values);
            } catch (SQLiteException e) {
                Log.e("Insert Quotes", e.toString());
                result=-1;
            } finally {

                mSQLiteDB.close();
            }

            if (result == -1) {
                return false;
            } else {
                return true;
            }

        }
```

Comment: Validate before inserting

Comment: That only i dont know?

Comment: Well answering that will require us to know, how you are inserting data and data type of the values etc.. Share some code so you can get some help

Comment: Ok, the parts are free text or some specific values ?

Comment: Parts are added on based of iPartNo that is integer